# How to launch a Shortcut with Spaces in Java using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, execute, processbuilder, shortcut-file

This is the code I would use normally to execute a Shortcut file (.lnk)

```
  //Get Directory
  String currentDir = new File(game.getGamePath()).getCanonicalPath();

  //Parse Directory to put apostrophes around shortcut name    
  currentDir = currentDir.substring(0, currentDir.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1) + '"' +                      
  currentDir.substring(currentDir.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, currentDir.length()) + '"';

  //prep the launcher
  ProcessBuilder processBuild = new ProcessBuilder();
  processBuild.command("cmd", "/c", "start" ,"/wait", "", currentDir);

  //launch 
  Process = processBuild.start();
  try {
       Process.waitFor();
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

  }
```

Problem is when the Shortcut file name has spaces I get an Error from windows saying
it could not load [WordAfterSpace.ink]

For example say I had a currentDir with value [Desktop\A B.lnk]

Parsed it would be [Desktop\"A B.ink"] and this works perfectly on the command prompt.

problem is I would get this Error if I were to use the above code:

> Windows cannot Find 'B.ink', Make sure you typed the name in correctly and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use \" to get double quotes within strings
Also, quote the whole link from the start instead of just the link name as you might have other spaces before it. That will save you from trouble.

Comment: I tried that and all I get is a command prompt console that's pointed to the directory between the brackets

Comment: is it possible that you open the path then instead of the link by calling game.getGamePath()?

Comment: game.getGamePath() outputs a string containing the path extracted from a JFileChooser.

Comment: when you insert a path instead of an .lnk file the cmd opens the directory instead of running something.

Comment: try using .getSelectedFile() instead

Comment: that's What I use, and I store it in a String Variable called gamePath in a class called Game

Comment: Could you output the game.getGamePath() to check its correctness? If its a full file path, enclose it in the "quotes" having the substrings commented out.

Comment: Yes of course I have outputted it for correctness, that's the first thing you would do. as I explained, this issue only occurs for files names that have spaces in them. Putting Quotes around the entire path causes a new prompt to pop out with the cd being that path

Comment: Try it: Open cmd, type start then put quotes around any shortcut on the desktop, I keep getting a new prompt window.

Comment: you are right.. ok that may look weird but try placing the quote after the disk origin eg if it is in C:\blabla\bla spaces.lnk  make it C:"\blabla\bla spaces.lnk"

Comment: instead of last position of \ start quoting from first position, to the end

Comment: Nope get the same problem: Current Dir =  C:"\Users\Sammy\Desktop\Tribes Ascend.lnk" and it says it doesn't know where 'Ascend.lnk' is

Comment: how about removing the start and /wait parameters? try processBuild.command("cmd", "/c", "", currentDir);

Comment: Ah, there we go, that works perfectly now, not sure why it doesn't work with the start /wait but that seems to have resolved it.